# Build apk with buildozer

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

A project written in windows in a shared folder with an Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine when building apk gives the following error:

```
# Install platform
    # Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
    # Cwd /media/sf_kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    # Command failed: git config --get remote.origin.url
    # ENVIRONMENT:
    #     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
    #     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
    #     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'be_BY.UTF-8'
    #     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
    #     LC_PAPER = 'be_BY.UTF-8'
    #     LC_MONETARY = 'be_BY.UTF-8'
    #     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
    #     LANG = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
    #     MANAGERPID = '1027'
    #     DISPLAY = ':0'
    #     INVOCATION_ID = '3dbfb8013aca49edb2b5d958c1d85b56'
    #     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
    #     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
    #     USERNAME = 'dima'
    #     XDG_VTNR = '1'
    #     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
    #     LC_NAME = 'be_BY.UTF-8'
    #     XDG_SESSION_ID = '1'
    #     USER = 'dima'
    #     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
    #     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
    #     TEXTDOMAINDIR = '/usr/share/locale/'
    #     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/c85cbc7d_c2fe_4051_bc1d_97d78e0c71de'
    #     PWD = '/media/sf_kivy'
    #     HOME = '/home/dima'
    #     JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:22912'
    #     TEXTDOMAIN = 'im-config'
    #     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1192'
    #     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
    #     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
    #     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
    #     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
    #     LC_ADDRESS = 'be_BY.UTF-8'
    #     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=f4eac8e33d101ed76b23fc8662667fbb'
    #     LC_NUMERIC = 'be_BY.UTF-8'
    #     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
    #     WINDOWPATH = '1'
    #     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
    #     VTE_VERSION = '5202'
    #     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
    #     QT_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
    #     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
    #     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '2'
    #     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
    #     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
    #     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
    #     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.90'
    #     SHLVL = '1'
    #     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
    #     LC_TELEPHONE = 'be_BY.UTF-8'
    #     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
    #     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
    #     LOGNAME = 'dima'
    #     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=f4eac8e33d101ed76b23fc8662667fbb'
    #     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
    #     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
    #     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
    #     PATH = '/home/dima/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/dima/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/dima/Library/Python/3.7/bin'
    #     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'be_BY.UTF-8'
    #     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/dima-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1056,unix/dima-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1056'
    #     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
    #     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
    #     LC_TIME = 'be_BY.UTF-8'
    #     _ = '/home/dima/.local/bin/buildozer'
    # 
    # Buildozer failed to execute the last command
    # The error might be hidden in the log above this error
    # Please read the full log, and search for it before
    # raising an issue with buildozer itself.
    # In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

What can i do to fix it?
Maybe i made a mistake in specificatoin, but i only added some requirments like

```
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,scrapy
```

Or it impossible to use scrapy library with kivy?
Structure of the project:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY5xw.png)

I ran command cd /media/sf_kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android && git config --get remote.origin.url and it did nothig:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O377v.png)

Comment: Please run `cd /media/sf_kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android && git config --get remote.origin.url` in a terminal inside the virtual machine and edit the output into your post.

Comment: I ran this command, and it did nothing, as you can see in the picture attached to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Today I got the same issue (while everything has been working fine last week).
I a got it fixed somehow by updating everything using apt-get, then all pip packages, than downgrading git using this post https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/2319

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a VERY similar problem.  My error was the same.  My env was the same.  Wrote in windows 10 and compiling on wsl ubuntu env.  In short this error 'seems' to be caused by running the buildozer command using the non root user in wsl when the project folder was owned by root.  The windows 10 disk folders are all root owned root group.

To fix for myself, I copied the windows project folder, owned by root, to a non root user home folder in wsl.  The copied folder should now be owned by the non root user used to copy the folder.  I then ran the buildozer build command in the project folder owned by the user running the buildozer command.    The build completed and generated the apk file.  I verified this 2x, deleting the project folder for the non root user, copying it to the non root user's home folder and buildozing again.

If someone would explain why the git (infer) command fails and works due to this, that would be helpful.
Thanks.